# Awk - Help Print Record Number Of Found Result

Tags: awk, count, record, gawk

Ultimately I am wanting to verify all record lengths are equal to a preset length in a text file.
Such as, user inputs a record length of 20.
The script would check every line to make sure none are lower OR higher than 20 in length.

IF a record is found ... report the record number and print the record.
(what I don't know how to do is report the record number of the found result)

What I have so far is a batch script that has this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\awk.exe" "length($0) < %CorrectLength%" %1

"C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\awk.exe" "length($0) > %CorrectLength%" %1
```

%correctlength% is the amount the user will input.

Obviously these two commands will print any lines that are less than X or more than X...

How do I get it to also print the record number of the found results?
And is there a way I can make it do both of these commands in a single line?

Comment: The current record number is held in the built-in variable `NR`, so you can do something like `print NR ": " $0` to print a line preceded by it's line number.  As far as combining both commands in a single line, do you need anything more than `length($0) != ...` ?

Comment: I am sorry I have not used awk or anything like it before so for printing the line number with the result how should I add `print NR ": " $0` to the code?

`C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\awk.exe" "length($0) < %CorrectLength%" %1 | print NR ": " $0`

Comment: So after some trial and error I have come up with this `C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\awk.exe" "length > %correctlength% {print NR, $0}" %1'   Which works... but how would I get some static print in after NR?   ` Print NR ": " $0 ` does not like the ` : ` part.  Get a syntax error.

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out `"C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\awk.exe" "length > %correctlength% {print NR \": \" $0}" %1`

Comment: Well done! I was just about to comment that you needed to escape the quotes but I wasn't sure how to do it in windows.

Comment: The standard (and good!) advice for running tools from Windows is a) don't do it, get cygwin instead, and b) if that's not possible then save your awk script in a file and execute it as `awk -f script` to avoid the Windows quoting nightmare and resultant backslash-hell.

Comment: Thanks to all... The idea is to allow the user to drop 1 or multiple text files onto a batch script which will run the script on each file....I thank you for the Standard (GOOD!) advice...I may not understand it fully but I will try to work with it.  I am starting to understand the quote nightmare!  Thank you JAS for the other code you gave... Final code so far is:  `"C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\awk.exe" "length($0) != %correctlength% {print NR \": \" $0}" %1`